# Figure order (figure and figure* environments)

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column, starred-version

I am writing a two-column article and all my figures are included with the `figure` environment but one using `figure*` so that it can be displayed page-wide. The problem is that that specific figure is not displayed in the right figure order while others figures do. So I have this order of figures in my article: 6, 7, 12 (`figure*`), 8, 9, 10, 11, 13. Any idea why? Note, I am using the Springer template and I am not using any placement options (such as `H`).

Comment: Move the code for the `figure*` later in the document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6):

This is a known problem in LaTeX2e; it is fixed by loading the [`fixltx2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) package.